# How to create a conditional debug Visual Studio Code with node js

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a loop that have a huge iterations around 300 iteration it maybe small but i have a problem with debugging with this loop let us see the following code (example 
 and it doesn't belong to what the code exactly is).

```
const myVar = [
  { name: 'basil', age: 25 },
  { name: 'basil', age: 25 },
  { name: 'basil', age: 25 },
  { name: 'basil', age: undefined },// line number four
  { name: 'basil', age: 25 }
]
for (i = 0; i < myVar.length; i++) {
console.log(myVar[i].name + ' ' + myVar[i].age) // line code
}
```

Now as you see above there are 5 objects actually i have 300 objects with non dummy code, the for loop has a lot of lines of code. but this will be enough, 
if i enabled a break point at `//line code` i will need to continue 300 iteration until i reach an object like `//line number four` this  object has a problem as you see the age is undefined i need to trace the behavior only if this value is undefined, so i need to enable the break point only if it is undefined.
im able to create a workaround like checking for undefined and then enabling the debug, but i need something in debug configuration.
i took a look at [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) page but it didn't help me

Comment: It is unclear - you do not want to set a conditional breakpoint (right click on a breakpoint within your for loop, chose "expression" and try something like myVar[i].age == undefined which will only break when that is true), but you want something else - in a debug config?  What is wrong with the conditional breakpoint?

Comment: @Mark May you post it as answer ? it works like charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a conditional breakpoint within your for loop:

1. Right-click in the usual gutter area for the line where you want to set a breakpoint.
2. Choose "Add Conditional Breakpoint..."
3. Make sure "Expression" (the default) is chosen in the little drop-down box.
4. Type `myVar[i].age == undefined` in the text entry line, hit return and run your debug session.

There is an unbound command `editor.debug.action.conditionalBreakpoint` that could be set up as a keybinding if you do this a lot.